# xlsxwriter - legend for Excel pie Chart - python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have an excel file with 6 tabs (worksheets). Each worksheet is of the same structure and contains two columns - Col 1 contains brand names and Col 2 contains values corresponding to each brand. For each sheet in the the excel file, I want to make a pie chart showing % share for each brand.

The example xls file you can use to run the script on is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5JM3GwmhOyOeDMwM3dzWVZCNzQ)

The code i wrote is quite simple and generates the charts. The problem is that the legend for the chart takes serial number names instead of the names of the brand.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter as excel

       df = pd.read_excel("/Users/jack/Documents/python-pptx/filename", sheetname=None)


        workbook = excel.Workbook('/Users/jack/Documents/python-pptx/chart_pie.xlsx')

        for sheetname, data in df.iteritems():
            if len(data) > 0: 
                worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(sheetname)
                chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'pie'})
                worksheet.write_column('A1', data['Brand'])
                worksheet.write_column('B1', data['Share_of_interactions'])
                chart.add_series({'categories': '='+sheetname+'!$A$1:$A$'+str(len(data)),
                                  'values':     '='+sheetname+'!$B$1:$B$'+str(len(data)),
                                  'name':       '='+sheetname+'!$A$1:$A$'+str(len(data))})

                ## insert chart into the worksheet
                worksheet.insert_chart('C3', chart)

                ## Close the workbook
        workbook.close()
```

Here is a screen shot of the chart :

[image]

IF you notice in the chart the legend says 1, 2, 3 .. . . 7 . It actually should be saying the brand name . I've added the name parameter to `chart.add_series` as mentioned in the documentation of `xlsxwriter` - http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html . Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Mind sharing a sample of your dataframe `df`?

Comment: @JulienMarrec let me put that together and share it.

Comment: I've shared the link to an excel file. You can use that to run the script.

Comment: @JulienMarrec any luck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have a space in your sheet name, like `Sheet 1`. You need to enclose it in single quotes:

```
df = pd.read_excel("/Users/julien/Downloads/SO_Example_Df.xlsx", sheetname=None)


workbook = excel.Workbook('/Users/julien/Downloads/SO_chart_pie.xlsx')

for sheetname, data in df.items():
    if len(data) > 0: 
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(sheetname)
        chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'pie'})
        worksheet.write_column('A1', data['Brand'])
        worksheet.write_column('B1', data['Share_of_interactions'])
        # Here, add single quotes around the sheetname
        chart.add_series({'categories': "='"+sheetname+"'!$A$1:$A$"+str(len(data)),
                          'values':     "='"+sheetname+"'!$B$1:$B$"+str(len(data)),
                          'name':       'My pie chart'})

        ## insert chart into the worksheet
        worksheet.insert_chart('C3', chart)

## Close the workbook
workbook.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Great ! That worked - can you explain what `"='"+sheetname+"'!$A$1:$A$"` evaluates to ?

Comment: Add `print("='"+sheetname+"'!$A$1:$A$"+str(len(data)))` to the loop, you'll see it evaluates to e.g. `='Sheet 1'!$A$1:$A$7`. Same as how it would show in Excel if you select that data, it adds single quotes around the Sheet name if there's a space

Comment: Thanks again - great catch - I wouldn't have figured that out for a while if at all ! What gets my goat is if didn't evaluate to the exact-sheet name earlier , then why was the program still creating the charts?

Comment: That's the million dollar question isn't it? I'd speculate this works when creating the chart with the xlsxwriter api because it evaluates correctly within the python ecosystem. Then the link breaks when you open it in Excel

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, and in XlsxWriter, the names of the data points in a Pie Chart come from the "Categories". This is different from other "2D" chart types where the names come from the series name. This is because a pie chart is a special case of a single series chart.

Anyway, if you point your Categories to the names you want they will be displayed. Like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Some sample data to plot.
data = {'apples': 10, 'berries': 32, 'squash': 21, 'melons': 13, 'corn': 18}

# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df = pd.DataFrame([data], index=['Farm'])

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
excel_file = 'pie.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)

# Access the XlsxWriter workbook and worksheet objects from the dataframe.
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

# Create a chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'pie'})

# Configure the chart from the dataframe data.
chart.add_series({
    'categories': ['Sheet1', 0, 1, 0, 5],
    'values':     ['Sheet1', 1, 1, 1, 5],
})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('A4', chart)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Also, note the use of the list for the Categories and Values instead of range strings. This optional format is easier where dealing with variable data and it handles any sheet name quoting.

Output:

[image]

Comment: but I did point the categories to the name : `chart.add_series({'categories': '='+sheetname+'!$A$1:$A$'+str(len(data)),
                                  'values':     '='+sheetname+'!$B$1:$B$'+str(len(data)),
                                  'name':       '='+sheetname+'!$A$1:$A$'+str(len(data))})` . Even if I remove the `name` parameter , i am getting the same result !

Comment: Then it should work, as I showed in my example. Try leaving out the `name` range, that should only be a single point.